# MySQL/C commit failed with multi statements

Tags: mysql, c, connector

I tried work with MySQL/C with CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS and `autocommit=0` connect, however, which do not work well. I receive the error message below every time while `mysql_commit();`

> Error: mysql_commit() failed with  Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

It is strange that it will work well when I set `autocommit=1;`
BTW, all my commands just contain 'INSERT', so I think there should not be any "Commands out of sync" error for no 'RESULT' would be produced.

You all may never want read any code like this below, lol

my macros:

```
#ifndef MACRO_H_
#define MACRO_H_

#define DBOPEN(x) x=mysql_init(NULL);\
    if(x==NULL){\
        DBErrLog("Error: mysql_init() failed.");return 1;\
    }\
    if(mysql_options(x, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "ascii")){\
        DBErrLog("Warning: mysql_option() SET mysql_set_charset_name TO ascii failed.");\
    }\
    if(mysql_options(x, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET autocommit=0")){\
        DBErrLog("Warning: mysql_option() SET autocommit=0 failed.");\
    }\
    if(!mysql_real_connect(x, C_DBHOST, C_DBUSR, C_DBPWD, C_DATABASE, 0, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)){\
        DBErrLog("Error: connect to database failed with %s.", mysql_error(x));\
        return 1;\
    }

#define DBQUERY(x, y) if(mysql_query(x, y)){\
        DBErrLog("Error: mysql_query(%s) failed with  %s.", y, mysql_error(x));\
        return 1;\
    }

#define DBREALQUERY(x, y, z) if(mysql_real_query(x, y, z)){\
        DBErrLog("Error: mysql_real_query(%s) failed with  %s.", y, mysql_error(x));\
        return 1;\
    }

#define DBCOMMIT(x) if(mysql_commit(x)){\
        DBErrLog("Error: mysql_commit() failed with  %s.", mysql_error(x));\
        return 1;\
    }

#define RESCATCH(x, y) y=mysql_store_result(x);\
    if(y==NULL){\
        DBErrLog("Error: mysql_store_result() failed with %s.", mysql_error(x));\
        return 1;\
    }

#define DBCLOSE(x) mysql_close(x)

#define RESFREE(x) mysql_free_result(x)

#define ROWCATCH(x, y) (x=(MYSQL_ROW*)mysql_fetch_row(y))

#define SAPPEND(to, msg) {\
        const char *str=msg;\
        while(*str)*to++=*str++;\
    }

#define IAPPEND(to, key) {\
        char buf[16];\
        sprintf(buf, "0x%x", key);\
        SAPPEND(to, buf);\
    }

#define STOIP(to, key) {\
        sscanf((char*)key, "%d", to);\
    }

#define ESAPPEND(sql, to, from, size) to+=mysql_real_escape_string(sql, to, from, size)

#define SERIALIZE(to, from, size) {\
        char *p=(char*)from;\
        size_t i;for(i=0;i<size;i++)\
            *to++=*p++;\
    }

#define SERIAPPEND(sql, to, from, size) {\
        char bufh[256], *buft;\
        buft=bufh;\
        SERIALIZE(buft, from, size);\
        ESAPPEND(sql, to, bufh, size);\
    }

#define UNSERIALIZE(to, from, size) {\
        char *dst=(char*)to;\
        char *src=(char*)from;\
        size_t i;for(i=0;i<size;i++)\
            *dst++=*src++;\
    }

#endif /* MACRO_H_ */
```

my error codes:

```
int CamInsert(void *vHead, void *vTail, void *vK){
    if(vTail<=vHead)return 2;
    char bufHead[C_BUFSIZE], *bufTail;
    MYSQL *sql;
    DBOPEN(sql);
    bufTail=bufHead;
    p2_t *head=(p2_t*)vHead;
    p2_t *tail=(p2_t*)vTail;
    p2_t *p2;
    SAPPEND(bufTail, "INSERT INTO p2(idxSelf, idxCam, idx3d, pos, ent) VALUES");
    for(p2=head; p2!=tail; p2++){
        if(p2!=head)SAPPEND(bufTail, ", ");
        SAPPEND(bufTail, "(");
        IAPPEND(bufTail, p2->idxSelf);
        SAPPEND(bufTail, ", ");
        IAPPEND(bufTail, p2->idxCam);
        SAPPEND(bufTail, ", ");
        IAPPEND(bufTail, p2->idx3d);
        SAPPEND(bufTail, ", '");
        SERIAPPEND(sql, bufTail, p2->pos, sizeof(float)*2);
        SAPPEND(bufTail, "', '");
        SERIAPPEND(sql, bufTail, p2->ent, sizeof(unsigned char)*C_DIMSIZE);
        SAPPEND(bufTail, "')");
    }
    cam_t *cam=(cam_t*)malloc(sizeof(cam_t));
    cam->idxSelf=head->idxCam;
    cam->idxGroup=cam->idxSelf;
    cam->adjusted=0;
    int *K=(int*)vK, i, j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            cam->K[i][j]=K[i*3+j];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            cam->P[i][j]=(i==j)?1.0f:0.0f;
    SAPPEND(bufTail, "; INSERT INTO cam(idxSelf, idxGroup, adjusted, K, P) VALUES(");
    IAPPEND(bufTail, cam->idxSelf);
    SAPPEND(bufTail, ", ");
    IAPPEND(bufTail, cam->idxGroup);
    SAPPEND(bufTail, ", ");
    IAPPEND(bufTail, cam->adjusted);
    SAPPEND(bufTail, ", '");
    SERIAPPEND(sql, bufTail, cam->K, sizeof(double)*3*3);
    SAPPEND(bufTail, "', '");
    SERIAPPEND(sql, bufTail, cam->P, sizeof(double)*3*4);
    SAPPEND(bufTail, "')");
    free(cam);
    DBREALQUERY(sql, bufHead, bufTail-bufHead);
    DBCOMMIT(sql);
    DBCLOSE(sql);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: Why create a buggy macro `SAPPEND` (whcih doesn't null-terminate the result) when there is a working library function `strcat`? You should also convert your macros to functions.

Comment: Also, using parameters in your SQL statements will make your code safer: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck, I think it's safe to use macro SAPPEND, because I just going to use mysql_real_query(), which work with the query length parameter. and strcat may have lower-effiency for maintaining a null-terminate instead of terminate-pointer. THX, all the same.

Comment: @klas-lindbäck, would you like to tell me more about 'parameters'? BTW, I think there currently is no error about my query statement, because it work will with autocommit. TXH, all the same.

Comment: You current code will fail if `ent` contains one single quote `'`. I haven't done any C coding against mysql, but you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to handle characters with special meaning in SQL. See for example www.kitebird.com/mysql-book/ch06-3ed.pdf (Encoding Special Characters and Binary Data on pages 399-402)

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck, I called mysql_real_escape_string() in my SERIAPPEND MACRO, my code work well now with the solution blow. Sincerely appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THERE WOULD BE SOME 'NULL-RESULT' PRODUCED WHILE WORKING WITH MULTI_STATEMENTS ONLY CONTAINS 'INSERT', SO WE SHOULD CALL SOME `mysql_next_result()` BEFORE EXECUTING `mysql_commit()`.

IN FACT, WE ARE ABLE TO GET THE ERROR MESSAGE WHILE THE MULTI_STATEMENTS QUERYING. SO I USED THE MACRO BLOW TO SUCCESSFULLY SOLVE MY OWN QUESTION.

```
#define DBMRFREE(x) {\
        while(1){\
            MYSQL_RES *r=mysql_store_result(x);\
            if(r!=NULL)mysql_free_result(r);\
            int msg=mysql_next_result(x);\
            if(msg>0){\
                DBErrLog("Error: mysql_next_result() failed whit %s.", mysql_error(x));\
            }else if(msg<0)break;\
        }\
    }
```

BTW, WHICH CAN ALSO LOG OUT THE ERROR MESSAGE WHILE THE MULTI_STATEMENTS QUERYING.

TY, ALL